# How do I log denials for offline charging mode

Tags: charging, logging, selinux, android-13

I've been able to fix offline charging animation on my device but it only works in permissive domain and whilst in enforcing it shows me random lines and i can't figure out a way to address the denials for it
Is there a specific way to log denials for charger service?

Comment: By "offline charging animation" you refer to the charging animation when the device is powered down?

Comment: Yes the one where it shows the percentage

Comment: Check for `avc` denials in kernel log (`dmesg -w`).